# Power Automate XML local-name syntax not working on SharePoint form library

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I think I have a syntax error with a Power Automate job that attempts to read XML files from a SharePoint form library consisting of old InfoPath forms. The automate step gets a list of the XML files then reads each one. [image: power automate reading xml files in SharePoint] Just to get started I'm tryin to grab the last name field from the XML. But when I look at the return of my compose statement is reads like this image and not a string. [image: xml results not a string] Below is snippet of the XML (note how InfoPath includes a lot of namespace noise) and the statement I'm using in the compose step to extract the name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-infoPathSolution name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:OnePRBv2:-myXSD-2017-05-05T14-19-13" solutionVersion="1.0.0.2488" productVersion="16.0.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="https://myportal.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/OnePRBv21/Forms/template.xsn"?>
<?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.4"?>
<?mso-infoPath-file-attachment-present?>
<my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls" xmlns:ma="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/metadata/properties/metaAttributes" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/dataFields" xmlns:q="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/queryFields" xmlns:dfs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution" xmlns:dms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/documentManagement/types" xmlns:tns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService" xmlns:s1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2017-05-05T14:19:13" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-US">
    <my:Last_Name>Smith</my:Last_Name>
```

Compose statement

```
xpath(xml(outputs('Get_file_content')?['body']),'/*[local-name()="myFields"]/*[local-name()="Last_Name"]')
```

I assume since I'm getting something back that means the syntax is correct but I'm not entirely sure that is true.

Update - looking at some other examples online I tried this syntax `xpath(xml(outputs('Get_file_content')?['body']),'/*[local-name()="myFields"]/*[local-name()="Last_Name"][0]')` but the result was just `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml in your question is not well formed; but try this on the actual xml and see if it works:

```
xpath(xml(outputs('Get_file_content')?['body']),'//*[local-name()="myFields"]//following-sibling::*[local-name()="Last_Name"]')
```

Comment: This originally gave me the same content-type response but when I added ```/text()``` to the end I can see the last name. Here's the full answer ```xpath(xml(outputs('Get_file_content')?['body']),'//*[local-name()="myFields"]//following-sibling::*[local-name()="Last_Name"]/text()')```. I'm going to try and look into the syntax you used to see if I can figure out why this was required.